# Finding first order derivative of function with sum to infinity

Tags: sequences-and-series, derivatives, summation, algorithms, infinity

I want to find the first order derivative to the following function in order to minimize the function.

$${\hat{C}}_3\left({\hat{y}}_3\right)=e_3{\hat{y}}_3-h_3(\ \lambda_3(L_3+1))+(h_3+b)\sum_{u={\hat{y}}_3}^{\infty}{(u-{\hat{y}}_3)}\frac{\left(\lambda_3\left(L_3+1\right)\right)^u}{u!}e^{{-\lambda}_3\left(L_3+1\right)}$$

Basically this is a twist on the clark and scarf method of finding optimal bases stocks. $e_3, h_3, \ \lambda_3(L_3+1)$ and $b$ are variables which are static for each of my calculations, so when I run a scenario these are fixed values for the specific scenario. ${\hat{y}}_3$ is the variable I want to optimize by minimizing ${\hat{C}}_3\left({\hat{y}}_3\right)$. I am mainly struggeling due to the ${\hat{y}}_3$ also being in the power of the summed function.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is ${\hat{y}}_3$ an argument of the function? Is ${\hat{y}}_3$ real variable?

Comment: Yes see $\hat{y}_3$ as the x of the function, this represent the stock kept and is the variable which is used to minimize costs.

Comment: What values ​​does $u$ presumably take on summation: $\hat{y}_3$, then what?

Comment: If $\hat{y}_3$ can be non-integer, then $u$ can be non-integer, then what is $u!$ ?

Comment: $\hat{y}_3$ should be an integer it stands for a stock level of an item. So u can only take integer values I believe. I really don't know how to approach this problem

Comment: There is no derivative for function of integer variable. You can consider first order difference $\hat{C}_3(\hat{y}_3+1)-\hat{C}_3(\hat{y}_3)$ and find when this difference is positive and when it is negative.